# Sharepoint 2013: people picker stopped working for add user in SP groups if use custom master page for system pages

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage

I am using custom master page for sharepoint system pages. When I try to add user, for example adding the user to some sharepoint group, it does not give auto fill suggestions or resolve any user. I tried to debug and found the weird error in console window:
Earlier it was working fine and suddenly it stopped working.

> **Error Starts**
>
> Uncaught TypeError: a.set_allowOnlyEmailAddresses is not a
>   functionSPClientPeoplePicker.GetPeoplePickerQueryParameters @
>   cdn.sharepointonline.com/9374/_layouts/15/16.0.4316.1200/clientpeoplepicker.js:1SPClientPeoplePicker.AddPickerSearchQuery
>   @
>   cdn.sharepointonline.com/9374/_layouts/15/16.0.4316.1200/clientpeoplepicker.js:1SPClientPeoplePicker_CallbackPopulateAutoFillFromEditor
>   @
>   cdn.sharepointonline.com/9374/_layouts/15/16.0.4316.1200/clientpeoplepicker.js:1(anonymous
>   function) @
>   cdn.sharepointonline.com/9374/_layouts/15/16.0.4316.1200/autofill.js:1
>
> **Error Ends**

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that sp.js and sp.runtime.js files were being referenced locally(ofcourse not the suggested way), which won't work well if SPO has update on those files.

**After adding the new CDN reference and removing the local reference it works fine.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your custom master page has the all related scripts like

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js?rev=jvJC3Kl5gbORaLtf7kxULQ%3D%3D"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sposuitenav.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?culture=en%2Dus&name=SP%2ERes"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>

    <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```

are loaded. if any one script is missing then the it won't work how it was expected, make sure what scripts you need and refer that in page.